Getting HttpMessageNotWritableException when trying to return List<UUID> in response body in SpringBoot
I'm getting following error if I try to return List which I get from field in my entity class. If I create List myself then I don't get this error. I'm using SpringBoot 3.3.2 with Java 17.
Error:
{
  "message": "Exception occurred: HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.UUID (java.lang.String and java.util.UUID are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')",
}

Complete error log with stack trace:
{
  "@timestamp": "2024-08-10T10:43:56.580637+05:30",
  "@version": "1",
  "message": "Exception stack trace: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.UUID (java.lang.String and java.util.UUID are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:492)\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:114)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:297)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:245)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\n\tat com.github.foodie.config.FilterConfig.doFilter(FilterConfig.java:26)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)\nCaused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.UUID (java.lang.String and java.util.UUID are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') (through reference chain: com.github.foodie.controllers.response.GenericResponse[\"data\"]->com.github.foodie.dtos.TestDto1[\"testDto2\"]->com.github.foodie.dtos.TestDto2[\"uuidList2\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:402)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:373)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:345)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContentsUsing(IndexedListSerializer.java:148)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:88)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:183)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:183)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:183)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:502)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:341)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1574)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1061)\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:483)\n\t... 51 more\nCaused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.UUID (java.lang.String and java.util.UUID are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.UUIDSerializer.serialize(UUIDSerializer.java:24)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContentsUsing(IndexedListSerializer.java:142)\n\t... 68 more\n",
  "logger_name": "com.github.foodie.advices.ExceptionAdvice",
  "thread_name": "http-nio-8082-exec-3",
  "level": "INFO",
  "level_value": 20000,
  "correlationId": "1667a21f-358f-4066-a3bb-bc6c19cacb59"
}

Controller Class
For testing purpose, I'm calling OrderRequestEntity directly from here and I've made sure that entity exists in database for given UUID. You can find OrderRequestEntity class after TestDto1, TestDto2 and GenericResponse in this post.
    @GetMapping("/res1")
    private ResponseEntity<GenericResponse<TestDto1>> responseTest1(@RequestParam Integer num) {
        TestDto2 testDto2 = new TestDto2();
        List<UUID> uuidList = new ArrayList<>();
        switch (num) {
            case 1: {
                uuidList.add(UUID.randomUUID());
                uuidList.add(UUID.randomUUID());
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                OrderRequestEntity entity = orderRequestRepository.findById(UUID.fromString("158790c2-ce63-4d00-b053-33f5a72782e7")).orElse(null);
                uuidList = entity.getItems();
            }
        }

        testDto2.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
       testDto2.setUuidList2(uuidList);

        TestDto1 testDto1 = new TestDto1();
        testDto1.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        testDto1.setTestDto2(testDto2);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new GenericResponse<>(true, "response got", testDto1));
    }


TestDto1

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TestDto1 {
    private UUID id;
    private TestDto2 testDto2;;
}


TestDto2
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TestDto2 {
    private UUID id;
    private List<UUID>  uuidList2;
    private Point point1;
    private Point point2;
}

GenericResponse
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GenericResponse<T> {
    private boolean success;
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private String message;
    private String correlationId = MDC.get("correlationId");
    private T data;

    public GenericResponse(boolean success, String message, T data) {
        this.success = success;
        this.message = message;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public GenericResponse(T data) {
        this.success = true;
        this.data = data;
    }
}

OrderRequestEntity (Here the field which I'm interested in is "items", for which I've written converter to convert it to JSON when we're storing it in DB and back to List when we're trying to get items from the entity).
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_request")
public class OrderRequestEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "restaurant_location", columnDefinition = "Geometry(Point, 4326)")
    private Point restaurantLocation;

    @Column(name = "delivery_location", columnDefinition = "Geometry(Point, 4326)")
    private Point deliveryLocation;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private CustomerEntity customerEntity;

    @Column(name = "customer_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private UUID customerId;

    @Column(name = "restaurant_id")
    private UUID restaurantId;

    @Convert(converter = UUIDListConvertor.class)
    @Column(name = "items")
    private List<UUID> items;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "payment_type")
    private PaymentType paymentType;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "order_request_status")
    private OrderRequestStatusType orderRequestStatusType;

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Instant createdOn;

    @Column(name = "updated_on")
    private Instant updatedOn;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        this.createdOn = this.updatedOn = Instant.now();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        this.updatedOn = Instant.now();
    }
}

UUIDListConvertor
@Converter
public class UUIDListConvertor extends JsonConverter<List<UUID>> {

}

JsonConverter
@Converter
public class JsonConverter<T> implements AttributeConverter<T, String> {
    private final TypeReference<T> typeReference = new TypeReference<T>() {};
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(T object) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to serialize JSON data", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T convertToEntityAttribute(String json) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to deserialize JSON data", e);
        }
    }
}

pom.xml

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-database-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.0</version>
        </dependency>

Expected outcome is that List is properly set in TestDto2 and we get it in response as well. But when I set it from OrderRequestEntity, I get an error shared above. This error does not show up when we manually add uuids to the list. I suspect it is due to convertor which is associated with items field in OrderRequestEntity.
To check if that is the issue I used debugger and I observed that values are successfully getting set in the List uuidList2 of TestDto2 but at the time when program reaches the end to give response, error occurs.

Following @JAsgarov advice, if I override the method in UUIDListConvertor and pass the correct TypeReference myself then program works as expected.
Here what I wrote in UUIDListConvertor

@Converter
@Slf4j
public class JsonConverter<T> implements AttributeConverter<T, String> {
    private final TypeReference<T> typeReference = new TypeReference<T>() {};
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(T object) {
        log.info("converting to database column");
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to serialize JSON data", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T convertToEntityAttribute(String json) {
        log.info("converting to entity attribute");
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to deserialize JSON data", e);
        }
    }

But I couldn't understand why T in JsonConvertor is not correctly getting evaluated to List<UUID>. Here's how TypeReference looks in debugger


Please post the complete exception including all causes as printed in your applications log

my guess is this is an erasure problem and in runtime passting List<Whatever> as T doesn't get correctly evaluated to correct TypeReference. Would be good for you to check what it evaluates to with debugger. Solution is probably just overriding the methods in UUIDListConvertor and passing the correct TypeReference yourself

@FlorianCramer I've edited the answer with complete error log, you can check now.
@JAsgarov Overriding the methods in UUIDListConvertor and passing correct TypeReference worked but I'm not able to understand why is T not getting correctly evaluated at runtime. I've updated the answer with debugger screenshot showing TypeReference, you can check for reference.

erasure is a bit complicated topic, but simply put the generics information that you use between < and > is only evaluated at compile time and discarded at runtime. Therefore the TypeReference has to be calculated in compile time, in runtime it is no longer there to be evaluated.

u should post and accept your own answer, so people searching for the same problem can see the solution

Following @JAsgarov advice, if I override the method in UUIDListConvertor and pass the correct TypeReference myself then program works as expected. Issue seems to be the way erasure works in Java, as pointed out by @JAsgarov in comment section of the question.
Here what I wrote in UUIDListConvertor.

@Converter
@Slf4j
public class JsonConverter<T> implements AttributeConverter<T, String> {
    private final TypeReference<T> typeReference = new TypeReference<T>() {};
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(T object) {
        log.info("converting to database column");
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to serialize JSON data", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T convertToEntityAttribute(String json) {
        log.info("converting to entity attribute");
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to deserialize JSON data", e);
        }
    }

